# Array as Enum member fails compilation

Tags: java, enums

This doesn't work:

```
    public enum TestEnum {

    FOO({"foobar","foobaz"}); //This fails

    private final String[] indicators;

    TestEnum(String[] indicators){
     this.indicators = indicators;
    }

    private String[] getIndicators(){
    return this.indicators;
    }
```

The code above fails to compile. The one below compiles successfully

```
    public enum TestEnum {

FOO(new String[3]); //This is okay. Why?

private final String[] indicators;

TestEnum(String[] indicators){
    this.indicators = indicators;
}

private String[] getIndicators(){
    return this.indicators;
}
```

My objective here is to provide an enum that can be represented by multiple Strings. I am aware of `EnumMap`, but it won't work here as the mapping I'm interested in is from `<String,enum>`. I'm also aware I could use a plain `Map`. I guess I'm mostly curious why No. 1 won't work for me.

Comment: Probably best fix is to use `private TestEnum(String... indicators ) {`, lose the braces and put a `.clone()` into the get method (or make it an unmodifiable `List`).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline,the varargs will work best eventually when I don't want to statically size the arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `{"foobar","foobaz"}` is an array initializer and will work only when directly declaring an array.

Try prepending `new String[]`:

```
FOO(new String[] {"foobar","foobaz"});
```

According to the [JLS, section 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create
>   an array and provide some initial values.

That is, you need an [array creation expression, section 15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

Comment: I'm checking that part of JLS but it doesn't provide the info about using `new Object[]` before `{}` explicitly.

Comment: Section 10.6 referred to 15.10, where an array creation expression is actually defined.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `new` is required because you can't declare/assign to a variable and use the initializer within the call (e.g. `someMethod(String[] foo = {"string"})` isn't legal). Only way to do it inside the arg list is with `new` to create, initialize, and pass an anonymous array

Comment: @BrianRoach thanks! That's the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    FOO(new String[] { "foobar", "foobaz" });

    private final String[] indicators;

    TestEnum(String[] indicators) {
        this.indicators = indicators;
    }

    private String[] getIndicators() {
        return this.indicators;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why it won't work as is? It's basically the same thing!

Comment: You need to specify the `String` array as its not a declaration

Answer (score 2):

`{"foobar","foobaz"}` will only work when initializing a recently declared array, for example:

```
String[] foos = {"foobar","foobaz"};
```

If you declare the array and try to give this value, it won't compile:

```
String[] foos;
foos = {"foobar","foobaz"};
```

If you want to make it compile, you must add `new String[]` before the `{}`:

```
String[] foos;
foos = new String[]{"foobar","foobaz"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
FOO({"foobar","foobaz"});
```

try

```
FOO(new String[]{"foobar","foobaz"});
```

This way the compiler knows the type of the array you are passing.